# Symfony installation exception in my wamp server

Tags: symfony

```
E:\wamp\www>composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject
```

I got the following error while running the above command from my CMD

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  $id must be a string, or an Alias object.



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handl
ing the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repos
itory-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--n
o-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
[package] [directory] [version]
```

When i try to open this in Browser it is displaying following things

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '$id must be a string, or an Alias object.' in E:\wamp\www\jicc\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 684
( ! ) Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: $id must be a string, or an Alias object. in E:\wamp\www\jicc\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php on line 684
```

Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  243936  {main}( )   ..\app.php:0
2   0.0168  1858928 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle( )  ..\app.php:28
3   0.0168  1859248 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot( )    ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2442
4   0.0214  2030936 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer( ) ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2411
5   0.1249  6222584 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile( )  ..\bootstrap.php.cache:2633
6   0.1365  6246912 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile( ) ..\ContainerBuilder.php:614
7   0.1365  6252376 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process( )    ..\Compiler.php:117
8   0.1367  6253344 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process( )  ..\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
9   0.3882  11688728    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension->load( )  ..\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:55
10  0.3993  11915400    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailer( )   ..\SwiftmailerExtension.php:53
11  0.3996  11924184    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\SwiftmailerExtension->configureMailerSpool( )  ..\SwiftmailerExtension.php:92
12  0.3997  11930016    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->setAlias( ) ..\SwiftmailerExtension.php:223
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: It failed during the clearing the cache of the project,It's not so important. I think your project is now ready and installed,Am I wrong?

Comment: @soroush gholamzadeh yep that's true. Project has been running successfully. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Your welcome,But consider that whenever you want to clear the cache, You should clear it manually because of this error, I hope others help you about this problem

Comment: @soroush gholamzadeh. Please ignore my previous comment. getting the fatal errors while opening the project in browser. Please go through the question once again. to find the browser output

Comment: Wtf? NO, it is not ok if the clearing of the cache fails with an exception.

Comment: @lxg please correct me if m wrong. i'm a newbie to symfony. I guess the first the problem is with "[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  $id must be a string, or an Alias object.".

Comment: siva: I was actually refering to @soroushgholamzadeh. And whatever the problem is, it should not happen on a fresh install. I guess this is some sort of bug (see my answer below).

Comment: @lxg I say again,It's not a critical bug that fails the running. It is a bug should be considered and be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on a fresh install of Symfony, please consider running the stable and long-term supported version of Symfony, currently 2.7:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.7.*"
```

If this works for you, then please post a bug report in [symfony/symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard). Maybe a bug has been introduced in the latest version.

Comment: By following your suggestion i tried some other standard versions (2.7.1 , 2.7.2 and 2.7.5) but not able to succeed.

Comment: @siva: Same bug as before? Or some other issue?

Comment: facing same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to use -v switch with your command e.g. "php app/console cache:clear -v" to view backtrace.

Some more about my case:
I moved all parameters from parameters.yml file to PHP environment variables and then had this issue. Basically SwiftMailer stopped to see parameters values. Using -v switch I've found the cause.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that if I clear my cache manual e.g. using linux's rm -rf app/cache/* command, I got en error. But if I clear the cache using app/console cache:clear command, everything works fine.